# W3 Validation errors

Tags: html, css

I have 12 errors, but some are just pure non existent. I'm using the smarty templating engine.

Doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

[Here's the error report](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.euroworker.no/Target-7050-Softphone-USB-Duo.220&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), but the "duplicate specification of attribute "value"" simply isn't true according to my .tpl: [jsfiddle of .tpl here](http://jsfiddle.net/GkFNY/)

```
{textfield class="quetext" value="Epost*" onblur="if(this.value=='') 
this.value='Epost*';" 
onfocus="if(this.value=='Epost*') this.value='';"}
```

Also, does a `textarea` require the attribute "rows" and "cols"? I thought that was only for tables?

And I don't understand what the two errors at the end mean:

```
Line 586, Column 80: Attribute value redefined...
```

Please help!

Thanks :)

(Sorry if things chop and change, I'm working on the valdiation now, to tidy up as many errors as possible.)

Comment: I would suggest separating your JS from your HTML using an external script file.  It should make it a little easier to work with the validation process.

Comment: I'd suggest going further and not using the default value as a substitute `<label>`. It's semantically wrong and impossible for screen reader users to access (element gets focus, "label" goes away, nothing for the screen reader to read out).

Comment: I shall try to separate that JS now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the "duplicate specification of attribute "value"" simply isn't true according to my .tpl:

The validator is only looking at your output. You have the value attribute in there twice, no matter what you .tpl says.

> Also, does a textarea require the attribute "rows" and "cols"?

Yes

> I thought that was only for tables?

Tables don't have those attributes at all

> Line 586, Column 80: Attribute value redefined...

You have, in essence: `<foo value="something" value="something">`

This is the same problem as before, except it is the error on the second one rather than the first.

Comment: Don't be absurd, `<foo>` isn't a real HTML element ;-)

Comment: Thanks, added cols and rows. About the `value=""` how would I prevent another value being added? What is inserting this new value?

Comment: I don't know what template language you are using, let alone how it works.

Comment: Still don't know how it works. I haven't touched PHP for anything but the most trivial toy scripts for over half a decade.